# Starting chromedriver with saved passwords enabled

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Everytime that I start the Chrome web browser, using chromedriver, it starts up clean with any custom settings disabled. I have a case where I am logged in on a website and I want to access the account to get some information. However, the newly opened browser is not logged into the account anymore. Even when I open a new browser manually I am still logged in on that same page. Is there a way to enable custom settings? Preferably in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ChromeOptions` as below :-

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

String chromeDirPath = "provided here a path where you want to custom chrome dir which could be use everty time you launch"
//ensure chromeDirPath exist in dir

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir="+chromeDirPath);

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("url");
```

Now it will maintain your custom browser setting at `chromeDirPath`

Hope it will help you.